# Print the day of the week provided the month and date (Eg. Month: 5, Day: 18 ) (Given Month:1 and Day: 1 is “Monday”)

Tags: python

I don't want to use the weekday function for this as it is simplified due to the conditions. 
Something like this.

```py
weekday = {
    "Mon": 0,
    "Tue": 1,
    "Wed": 2,
    "Thu": 3,
    "Fri": 4,
    "Sat": 5,
    "Sun": 6
}


def wd(s, k):
    s = list(weekday.values())[list(weekday.keys()).index(s)]
    k %= 7
    result = (s + k) % 7
    return result


for key, value in weekday.items():
    if value == wd('Sat', 1):
        print(key)
```

Comment: I don’t understand the relation between your code and the question.

Comment: Am I missing something, or isn't the first line of `wd()` equivalent to `s = weekday[s]`?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```
import datetime
import calendar
my_date = datetime.date(2020,5,19)
print(calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()])
```

prints the name of the day..